# Fitch Notation Subderivations and Sequents

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am using [Fitch Notation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz_GnvUal7VccFpLM1lDWTFHZk0/view?usp=sharing) and am curious how you would write this one subderivation with just syntactic consequences (⊢)? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I was thinking you could maybe write it like this $(A, B, (C\vdash B))\vdash (C\rightarrow B)$, but I am still unsure.

Comment: You can use the Natural Deduction formalism for the ($\to$-I): if $\Gamma, C \vdash B$, then  $\Gamma \vdash C \to B$. See e.g. [IEP](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) for the rule.

Comment: How would you do that then? Would your {C} be matched up to my {C ⊢ B}? I am confused as to what terms go where.

Comment: The symbol $\Gamma, C \vdash B$ reads: "from the set $\Gamma$ plus $C$ of assumptions, $B$ is derivable".

Comment: The symbol $\Gamma \vdash C \to B$ reads: "from the set $\Gamma$ of assumptions, $C \to B$ is derivable".

Comment: This is the reason way I suggest **not** to use your proposed symbolis: it is too convoluted and difficult to read (we have already difficulty in reading the "standard" one...)

Comment: Could I see how you would write this one example using natural deduction? If you wrote that in the answer section, I think that would help me out a lot with my question.

Comment: The way I'm reading it is: "if $A,B,C \vdash B$, then $A,B \vdash C \to B$".

Comment: That hurts my brain, but I get it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58583/discussion-between-will-and-mauro-allegranza).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reading your symbolism as follows:

> "if $A,B,C ⊢ B$, then $A,B ⊢ C→B$.

If correct, this is an application of the rule ($\to$-I) of [Natural Deduction](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) that formalize the inference:

> if we have a derivation of $B$ from assumptions $A,B$ and $C$, we can produce a new derivation of $C \to B$ from assumptions $A$ and $B$.